Merge in Snowflake - SCD Type 2 covering all possibilities
I'm trying to write a merge statement in Snowflake that covers the following scenarios:

Data in source but not target - insert
Data in source and target, but source has changed - insert new record, update existing
Data no longer in source but is in target - update existing

I have developed working code that covers scenarios 1 & 2, but am struggling with scenario 3. Hopefully its something obvious I'm missing!
This is the code block i have currently for the merge statement covering scenarios 1 & 2. The issue with scenario 3 is that at the moment its meeting the not matched criteria, and trying to insert a new record where as i want to update the existing only.
MERGE INTO <TARGET_TABLE> T USING
(
    WITH UPDATE_CHECK AS
    (
        <GENERATE DATA>
    )
    SELECT
    P.*,
    HASH(P.<PRIMARY_KEYS>) AS MERGEKEY,
    NULL AS SOURCE_MATCH,
    NULL AS TARGET_MATCH
    FROM
    UPDATE_CHECK P
    UNION
    SELECT
    S.*,
    IFF(S.<PK> IS NULL,'NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE','MATCHED BY SOURCE') AS SOURCE_MATCH,
    IFF(T.<PK> IS NULL,'NOT MATCHED BY TARGET','MATCHED BY TARGET') AS TARGET_MATCH
    FROM
    UPDATE_CHECK S
    FULL JOIN
    <TARGET_TABLE> T
    ON
    S.<PK> = T.<PK> AND
    S.<PK> = T.<PK>...
    WHERE
    T.END_DATE IS NULL AND
    HASH(S.<COLUMNS THAT MAY CHANGE>) <> HASH(T.<COLUMNS THAT MAY CHANGE>)
) S
ON
HASH(T.<PRIMARY_KEYS>) = S.MERGEKEY

WHEN NOT MATCHED AND MERGEKEY IS NULL AND TARGET_MATCH IN ('NOT MATCHED BY TARGET','MATCHED BY TARGET') THEN INSERT
<DATA TO INSERT>

WHEN MATCHED AND
TARGET_MATCH IS NULL AND
T.END_DATE IS NULL AND
(
    S.<COLUMNS THAT MAY CHANGE> <> T.<COLUMNS THAT MAY CHANGE>
)
THEN UPDATE
SET
T.END_DATE = SYSDATE()




Does your source contain deletion information or is it just a snapshot of your source table? What do you want to do when a deletion happens - delete from your target, flag the target record, etc? Just an fyi, if you’re processing a complete copy of your source every day, rather than a delta, this is going to get computationally very expensive if you have a significant volume of data (now or in the future)

Hi @NickW no delete information is contained in the source as far as i'm aware, i've asked the question of the Downstream Team if a flag or notification is available and awaiting a response. When a deletion happens i want the target record flagged/closed. At the moment this is going to be a monthly process, with circa 1.2m records and probably the biggest problem is the source data is received as a full load, not incremental

I would definitely push for an incremental extract that also included soft deletes. Given the current scenario, I would handle deletes in their own SQL statement and not try to force them into the merge statement - because for deletes your driver file is now your target table, not your source table

Hi @nickW thanks for the response, i'll ask the developers responsible for the upstream work to see what they can do, and will look to handle the deletes via a separate SQL statement! Thanks!
